# Long text in propertygrid dissappears

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I'm using propertygrid, and for some reason if a property holds text longer that 3000 chars the text doesn't appear. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The PropertyGrid control is not suitable for displaying such a large amount of data. It would be better to pop up a TextBox control or similar using the UITypeEditor.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302334.aspx) for more info on how to do this.

Edit: The link provides examples on how to extend the PropertyGrid to display non-standard values.

Comment: I'm using PropertyGrid, and that's what I need. also I don't know how long the string will be, usally it should be short, but I don't want it to disappear when it's too long.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you skip the PropertyGrid. But you may need to extend it to suit your particular needs. Check the link I posted.